# Get rows selected from Dt table shiny

Tags: r, shiny

WE all know that there is a built in function to get rows selected from DT table as shown below.
Right now, whenever the user clicks on any row at **any columns**, the row numbers are printed. But that should not happen. Instead, only when he clicks on row at **specific columns** only, the row numbers should be printed. IS this possible

```
output$tab <- renderDT({
datatable(iris, selection = 'single',escape = F)
})

observerEvent(input$tab_rows_selected{
print("Clicked")
})
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can use the event `cell_clicked`:

```
output$tab <- renderDT({
datatable(iris, selection = 'single',escape = F)
})

observerEvent(input$tab_cell_clicked{
specific_col_index <- c(1, 3)
if (input$tab_cell_clicked$col %in% specific_col_index) {
print("Clicked")
}
})
```

Comment: I think this is not what I was looking. I was looking for like, we should be able to click only  on specific columns(say column 1) that is it. :) If the user tries to click on any other columns, that should not happen

Comment: So you what you described in your original question is doable with my answer (it only prints "clicked" when you click on a certain column). But you want that the row only gets selected when you click on a certain column?

Comment: Yeah absolutely right. That’s what I was looking for

Comment: ok, then please update your question, thanks!